How can i fix the error - "Bad Colour Sequence" from line 31?
I am making a Python Turtle project that will let me input 3 colour values which then get used as a colour for a circle, then it should print the rgb values of the colour and the hex values in the text output.
This is the code:
import turtle 
from turtle import colormode
import random
import time
turtle.speed(0)

def randomchoi():
    turtle.colormode(255)
    randr = random.randint(0, 255)
    randg = random.randint(0, 255)
    randb = random.randint(0, 255)
    rand = (randr, randg, randb)
    turtle.color(rand)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.left(180)
    turtle.forward(55)
    turtle.left(135)
    turtle.clear()
    turtle.circle(100)
    turtle.end_fill()
    print(rand)
    hexrand = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (rand)
    print(hexrand)

def rgbselect():
    turtle.colormode(255)
    rgbr = input("Red = ")
    rgbg = input("Green = ")
    rgbb = input("Blue = ")
    rgb = (rgbr, rgbg, rgbb)
    turtle.color(rgb)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.left(180)
    turtle.forward(55)
    turtle.left(135)
    turtle.clear()
    turtle.circle(100)
    turtle.end_fill()
    print(rgb)
    hexrgb = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (rgb)
    print(hexrgb)
    

rgbselect()

Ignore randchoi because its working as i wanted, but the focus of my problem is "rgbselect".
The code works until its time for the turtle colour to be changed to the tuple rgb
What can i do?
I have tried to importing colormode from turtle directly, it made no difference though.
I have also tried changing the rgbr, rgbg, and rgbb to integers using:
import turtle 
from turtle import colormode
import random
import time
turtle.speed(0)

def randomchoi():
    turtle.colormode(255)
    randr = random.randint(0, 255)
    randg = random.randint(0, 255)
    randb = random.randint(0, 255)
    rand = (randr, randg, randb)
    turtle.color(rand)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.left(180)
    turtle.forward(55)
    turtle.left(135)
    turtle.clear()
    turtle.circle(100)
    turtle.end_fill()
    print(rand)
    hexrand = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (rand)
    print(hexrand)

def rgbselect():
    turtle.colormode(255)
    rgbr = input("Red = ")
    rgbg = input("Green = ")
    rgbb = input("Blue = ")
    **int(rgbr)
    int(rgbg)
    int(rgbb)**
    rgb = (rgbr, rgbg, rgbb)
    turtle.color(rgb)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.left(180)
    turtle.forward(55)
    turtle.left(135)
    turtle.clear()
    turtle.circle(100)
    turtle.end_fill()
    print(rgb)
    hexrgb = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (rgb)
    print(hexrgb)
    

rgbselect()

It didn't change the outcome, i also tried to do int(rgb) but that came up with a different error

Why is randomchoi in the code snippets? You never call it. Please post a [mre].

What error are you getting? (PS: unless turtle.color takes a tuple of strings as input, use the second version and delete the first code you posted as it's unlikely that it will work)

rgbr = input("Red = ") should be rgbr = int(input("Red = ")) to convert the inputs to integers.

@LuxGiammi It accepts either a tuple or multiple arguments.

@Barmar my comment was about a tuple of strings: in the first code sample they are all strings and not integers. Anyway, in the second version the conversions are done but not assigned to any variables, therefore are lost.

@LuxGiammi It doesn't allow multiple strings, either. It allows either a single string with a color name, 3 integers, or a tuple of 3 integers.

This question is similar to: What does bad color sequence mean in Python turtle?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The second version is likely correct, but you need to change each int(rgbr), int(rgbg), int(rgbb) with:
rgbr = int(rgbr)
rgbg = int(rgbg)
rgbb = int(rgbb)

Without any further information about the error, I cannot help further.
PS: I posted this answer before reading Barmar's comment, which is equivalent (i.e. doing rgbr = int(input("Red -> ")) and so on for each color component).
